# Where is all the Brute's base armor

Tags: mass-effect-3

Brutes are protected by thick, metal plates that can be shot off. Where are all the base armor plates? Does each armor plate require the same amount of damage to shoot off? Can the Brute pick up armor like the Cannibal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that all plates take the same damage to remove, and I don't believe they pick them up.
Confirmed on xbox.

Answer (score 0):

[A direct quote from Bioware programmer Brenon Holmes](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/10048855&lf=8) is illuminating, and provides some interesting information on the intended state of vulnerabilities:

> Ah... hmm - I'm not sure why your empirical testing would have come up with some of that - but here's how it's "supposed" to be.
>
> Brute
>
> - Takes reduced damage in the right arm
> - Takes greatly reduced damage in the claw
> - Armour Plates absorb damage until breaking (best to aim for exposed flesh, probably base of the neck?)
> - No other weak points

Comment: it doesn't exactly say *where* those armor plates are though, just that they absorb damage.

Comment: @yx. I agree it is only a partial answer so far. But it does highlight that not armor is not uniform.